# How to debug wxpython app that crashes deep in wxpython/python threading

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxpython app called h2hh.   A user on OSX is getting repeated crashes and has supplied the appended crash dump.

I don't even know where to start on debugging this!   Help?   How do I even start?   I'll be grateful even for some questions that might give me clues...

Thanks!

Full crash dump at http://gregories.net/images/crashdump.txt

```
Date/Time:       2012-10-13 00:40:50 +0200
OS Version:      10.8.2 (Build 12C60)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  11

Command:         h2hh
Path:            /Applications/h2hh.app/Contents/MacOS/h2hh
Version:         2.1.4 Beta (2.1.4 Beta)
Parent:          launchd [225]

PID:             31842
Event:           hang
Duration:        1.97s
Steps:           20 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookAir3,2
Active cpus:     2
Free pages:      311652 pages (-1327)
Pageins:         16 pages
Pageouts:        0 pages


Process:         h2hh [31842]
Path:            /Applications/h2hh.app/Contents/MacOS/h2hh
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [225]
UID:             501
Task size:       20328 pages (+470)
CPU Time:        1.936s

  Thread 0x69ee1    DispatchQueue 1          priority <multiple> cpu time   0.935s
  20 start + 52 (h2hh) [0x100000e24]
    20 main + 1438 (h2hh) [0x100004b6e]
      20 start + 13830 (h2hh) [0x1000043f6]
        20 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 392 (Python) [0x1018c3da8]
          20 PyRun_FileExFlags + 164 (Python) [0x1018c2af4]
            20 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 (Python) [0x1018a4326]
              20 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18189 (Python) [0x1018a109d]
                  20 ??? (Python + 672856) [0x1018a4458]
                    20 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                      20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3188 (Python) [0x10189d604]
                        20 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 (Python) [0x1018a4326]
                          20 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                            20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18189 (Python) [0x1018a109d]
                              20 ??? (Python + 672739) [0x1018a43e3]
                                20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18725 (Python) [0x1018a12b5]
                                  20 PyObject_Call + 97 (Python) [0x101808be1]
                                    20 ??? (Python + 109079) [0x10181aa17]
                                      20 PyObject_Call + 97 (Python) [0x101808be1]
                                        20 ??? (Python + 202123) [0x10183158b]
                                          20 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                                            20 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20406 (Python) [0x1018a1946]
                                              20 wxPySwigInstance_Check(_object*) + 223711 (_core_.so) [0x101d7244f]
                                                20 wxPyApp::MainLoop() + 76 (_core_.so) [0x101d26c3c]
                                                  20 wxAppConsoleBase::MainLoop() + 72 (libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib) [0x101fac6d8]
                                                    20 wxCFEventLoop::Run() + 55 (libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib) [0x1020a7607]
                                                      20 wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun() + 51 (libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib) [0x1021d40b3]
                                                        20 -[NSApplication run] + 517 (AppKit) [0x7fff8f48e283]
                                                          20 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128 (AppKit) [0x7fff8f496ed2]

blah blah

    1  CFArrayGetFirstIndexOfValue + 35 (CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8d575a83]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1  <executing in user space>
                                                                                                                                                                                  2  ??? (Python + 672739) [0x1018a43e3]
                                                                                                                                                                                    1  PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18189 (Python) [0x1018a109d]
                                                                                                                                                                                      1  ??? (Python + 672856) [0x1018a4458]
                                                                                                                                                                                        1  PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                                                                                                                                                                                          1  PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18011 (Python) [0x1018a0feb]
                                                                                                                                                                                            1  ??? (Python + 925773) [0x1018e204d]
                                                                                                                                                                                              1  ??? (Python + 955601) [0x1018e94d1]
                                                                                                                                                                                                1  PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 180 (Python) [0x10189bd94]
                                                                                                                                                                                                  1  PyObject_Call + 97 (Python) [0x101808be1]
                                                                                                                                                                                                    1  PyUnicodeUCS2_Join + 521 (Python) [0x10187b939]
                                                                                                                                                                                                      1  PyUnicodeUCS2_FromEncodedObject + 69 (Python) [0x101879155]
                                                                                                                                                                                                        1  <executing in user space>
                                                                                                                                                                                    1  PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22213 (Python) [0x1018a2055]
                                                                                                                                                                                      1  PyThread_release_lock + 22 (Python) [0x1018d4e06]
                                                                                                                                                                                        1  OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier$VARIANT$mp + 8 (libsystem_c.dylib) [0x7fff8e78ec9c]
                                                                                                                                                                                          1  <executing in user space>
                                                                                                                                                            1  ??? (Python + 672856) [0x1018a4458]
                                                                                                                                                              1  PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2103 (Python) [0x1018a42a7]
                                                                                                                                                                1  PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20406 (Python) [0x1018a1946]
                                                                                                                                                                  1  wxGBPosition_helper(_object*, wxGBPosition**) + 14799 (_core_.so) [0x101ddbc5f]
                                                                                                                                                                    1  PyEval_RestoreThread + 62 (Python) [0x1018a44fe]
                                                                                                                                                                      1  PyThread_acquire_lock + 107 (Python) [0x1018d4ecb]
                                                                                                                                                                        1  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff848c50fa]
                                                                                                                                                                         *1  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005b5d30]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're not calling a wx method directly from a thread. If you do, then you are doing something that's undefined and will cause issues. You have to use a wx thread safe method instead, such as wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent. If you call something like myControlSetValue() from within a thread, you'll have problems.

I recommend asking over on the wxPython mailing list as well. There are several Mac guys there including a couple of core devs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this, a good lead.   I _thought_ that I have CallAfter etc, but definitely something for me to start with!

Comment: Just came back to say that this was spot on.   I found a timer callback that called direct to wx instead of CallAfter()ing.   Thanks!